# SQL REGEXP_LIKE Show data with special characters excluding spaces

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I am trying to create a query where I want to find any string with a number shown below

```
REGEXP_LIKE (name, '[0-9]$')
```

I would also like to show the names that contain any special characters not including spaces (spaces are valid) I would also like this to be separate from the number example shown above.

Characters I want to check if in string

```
`~!@#$%^&*()_-+=?/\|][{}"':;><.,
```

Below doesn't work

```
REGEXP_LIKE( name, '[!#$%&()*+,\-./:;<=>?@[\\\]^`{|}~]' )
```

However I can't seem to get it to work, any help would be great.

Comment: Whenever you have a question, please post a little sample data (CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements for all tables involved, relevant columns only) so the people who want to help you can recreate the problem and test their ideas. Also post the exact results you want from that data, and explain why you want those results from that data. Lastly, don't post any images as they cant be cut and pasted.

Comment: @Beefstu does this help, I want to find strings ignoring spaces that contain any of the above special charaters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a WITH clause is a good way to set up test data and makes it real easy to try different test strings. Think of it like a temp table.  Your first `regexp_like()` tests for a number at the end of the string.  See below to test for a number anywhere in the string.  Use the posix regex shorthand `[[:punct:]]` to match punctuation characters.  I just combined all the examples into one query below.

```
with tbl(id, str) as (
  select 1, 'test' from dual union all
  select 2, 'test 1 test' from dual union all
  select 3, 'test 2' from dual union all
  select 4, '3 test' from dual union all
  select 5, '4 ` test' from dual union all
  select 6, 'test ~ test' from dual
)
select id, str
from tbl
where regexp_like(str, '[0-9]$') -- ends in a number
or regexp_like(str, '\d') -- contains a number anywhere
or regexp_like(str, '[[:punct:]]'); -- contains a punctuation character anywhere


        ID STR        
---------- -----------
         2 test 1 test
         3 test 2     
         4 3 test     
         5 4 ` test   
         6 test ~ test

5 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful and make more sense than a lot of other posts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the translate command to remove characters.

```
CREATE TABLE t (name) AS
SELECT 'Hello World' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Acx÷×' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '123 456 789' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '~!@#$%Xxv^&*()_+=\sv{}[]:”;’<,>./?' FROM DUAL

SELECT TRANSLATE(name, '~!@÷*#$%^&*()_+=\{}[]:”;’<,>./?',' ') as no_special_char
FROM t;

NO_SPECIAL_CHAR
Hello World
Acx×
123 456 789
 Xxvsv
```